# Flurry custom events with integer value and Displaying average in Flurry portal

Tags: ios, flurry

How to get average value of integer which sending through custom events

For Example:

```
EventName: AverageScore
```

Each users send the score to this event. Is it possible to view the average of this particular event in Flurry portal?

```
NSDictionary *scoreParam =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"180", @"score",nil];
[Flurry logEvent:@"AverageScore" withParameters:scoreParam];
```

We want to display the average of score in flurry portal which we send it from custom event mentioned above.

How to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the portal, but you can download a CSV report and use a spreadsheet or small script to read it and calculate the average and any other stats. Note that Flurry's CSV exports are truncated at 100,000 rows or so -- it may be necessary to limit the timeframe and use several reports (e.g. on a weekly or even daily basis).